# Angular access to "this" of controlled class from directive scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ecmascript-6

I implemented angular project with es6 style like this :

**controller.js**

```
export default class InsertController {

    constructor($scope) {
        this.$scope =$scope;
        this.data=[];
    }

    fillGrid(data) {

        console.log(data);

    }


}
InsertController.$inject = ['$scope'];
```

**Directive.js**

```
import angular from 'angular';

function FanGrid($compile) {
    return {

        replace: true,
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            //I want access to fillGrid method of controller
            scope.fillGrid(data);


        }

    }
}

export default angular.module('directives.fanGrid', [])
    .directive('fanGrid', FanGrid)
    .name;
```

**Now I want to know**

1. How to access and call `fillGrid()` method of controller in directive
2. How to acess to `"this"` of controller class from directive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use ES6 in angular1, you'd better implement a directive like this:

```
class FanGridController {
    constructor() {
        this.fillGrid('some data') //Output some data
    }
}

function FanGridDirective($compile) {
    return {
        replace: true,
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        controller: "FanGridController",
        scope: {
            fillGrid: "=?fillGrid",
            controllerThis: "=?controllerThis"
        }
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            //I want access to fillGrid method of controller
        },
        controllerAs: "vm",
        bindToController: true
    }
}

export { FanGridController, FanGridDirective }
```

With this implementation, the `this` is pointed to 'vm' in `FanGridController`. the `vm` is a attribute of `$scope` object. And all variables in the `scope:{}` can be accessed by `this`

The answer to your question is that you can make the fillGrid and controllerThis as a scope parameter and pass it in HTML template. Then call this method with `this.fillGrid`.

```
export default class InsertController {
    constructor($scope) {
        this.$scope = $scope;
        this.data = [];
    }

    fillGrid(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
}
InsertController.$inject = ['$scope'];
```

Pass the parameter in HTML

```
<fan-grid fill-grid="vm.fillGrid" controller-this="vm"></fan-grid>
```

Then call the method and access the controller's this in directive controller:

```
class FanGridController {
    constructor() {
        let controllerThis = this.controllerThis; 
        this.fillGrid('some data'); //Output some data
    }
}
```

or in link function:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    let controllerThis = $scope.vm.controllerThis;
    $scope.vm.fillGrid('some data') //Output some data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the controller belong to the directive itself, so they have a shared scope.

```
import angular from 'angular';
import directiveController from 'directive.controller.js';

export default () => ({
  bindToController: {
    someBinding: '='
  },
  replace: true,
  restrict: 'E',
  link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

    // To access a method on the controller, it's as simple as you wrote:
    scope.vm.fillGrid(data);

  },
  scope: true,
  controller: directiveController,
  controllerAs: 'vm'
});
```

Then your controller is as you wrote it:

```
export default class directiveController {

  constructor($scope) {
    this.$scope = $scope;
    this.data = [];
  }

  fillGrid(data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
}
```